# loop through servers and send single email with results instead of an email for each result

Tags: powershell

```
foreach ($server in '192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.6', '192.168.1.7') {
    
    $availablespace = [Math]::Truncate((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Credential $arpcred | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq 'C:' }).FreeSpace / 1GB)
    Write-Host $server has $availablespace GB of available space

    if ($availablespace -lt 10) {
        Write-Host $server only has $availablespace GB of available space
        Write-Host sending email
        Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject $subj -Body "$server only has $availablespace GB of available space" -SmtpServer $smtp -Credential $smtpcred -UseSsl -Port 587
    }
}
```

This will loop through a list of servers and send **an email for each server** that has less than 10GB of free space available on C:.

How can I change it so it will send **a single email** containing a list of all the servers with less than 10GB of free disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic array for the store value. Please find below code

```
 $serverlist= $null
    $serverlist= [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    foreach ($server in '192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.6', '192.168.1.7') {
        
        $availablespace = [Math]::Truncate((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Credential $arpcred | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq 'C:' }).FreeSpace / 1GB)
        Write-Host $server has $availablespace GB of available space
    
        if ($availablespace -lt 10) {
            $serverlist += $server 
        }
    }
    write-host $serverlist
```

You get all server list inside the **$serverlist**